# How do you access sessions and cookies from within a Rails gem or lib?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, plugins, rubygems

Im trying to create what will eventually be a rails gem (right now I have the files within the /lib directory) and I need to be able to read/write to and from cookies and sessions.  My methods will be called from within either the controller or views, so access to the cookies and sessions SHOULD be possible from within my gem but I cant figure out how to do it.

Ive tried extending ActionController to include my module as well as including ActionController inside my module and nothing works.  It could be the way Im running my tests since I feel like I have more success when trying to access my module and classes from within console.

Does anyone have any examples of accessing cookies and sessions from within gems/plugins etc?

Thanks,

Josh

Comment: Are you on Rails 2 or Rails 3?  Also, how exactly did you try to extend ActionController?  You should be able to create a mixin module and include it in ActionController.  Its fairly easy to do with engines if you are using Rails 3.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

See `session=env['rack.session']` in https://github.com/hassox/warden/blob/master/lib/warden/session_serializer.rb#L6.